# a list which has to be reordered according to the string array output

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have got a div with a class "select":

```
<div class="select">
    <label class="label"><input id="1" type="checkbox" value="1"/>
    <label for="1"><span></span></label> 1</label>

    <label class="label"><input id="2" type="checkbox" value="2"/>
    <label for="2"><span></span></label> 2</label>

    <label class="label"><input id="3" type="checkbox" value="3"/>
    <label for="3"><span></span></label> 3</label>
</div>
```

I use the second label tag to apply my own checkbox in a span tag:

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    display:none;
}
input[type="checkbox"] + label span {
    display:inline-block;        
    background:url(/images/checkbox.png) left top no-repeat;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label span {
    background:url(/images/checkbox.png) -15px top no-repeat;
}
```

now, I have got a string array, `ARRAY`, which can be `"1"` or `"2"` or `"3"` or a combination of them: `"1","2"` or `"3","1"` or `"2","1","3"` and so on. Lets say the `ARRAY = ["3","1"];`

The Idea is to sort the div elements according to the ARRAY order in the first place and checked and elements which are not offered in the ARRAY, should be at the bottom of the div.

```
---------
|[ ] 1  |
|[ ] 2  |
|[ ] 3  |
---------
```

the ARRAY has only order `["3","1"]`. `"2"` is not there

try to get:

```
---------
|[x] 3  |
|[x] 1  |
|[ ] 2  |
---------
```

Can somebody offer a logic or an algorithm? I am stack.

Comment: Moving elements in a list upon clicking them will get *very* confusing for a user.

Comment: But this is not what I want, I want to reorder this list just before any action with moving up or down happens.

Answer (score 0):

First off: I don't see why you need a second `label`. It seems like a bad idea.

Also you shouldn't use ID starting with numbers. Technically it's allowed by the HTML 5 specs, but that's a new thing and personally I'd avoid it.

To your problem: Basially you just need to loop over the array and move the checkboxes listed in the array to the top. If you loop over it backwards it gets even easier:

```
var checkboxes = ["3", "1"]; // Example

var $select = jQuery(".select");
for (var i = checkboxes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  var checkbox = $select.find('#' + checkboxes[i]).parent();
  $select.prepend(checkbox);
}
```